# Why does importing a function from a file give "Unresolved reference [file name]"?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, python-import

I have two files in Intellij in the same directory: `__init__.py` and `__resources__.py`.

`__init__.py` is set as the script in my "Run Configuration", so it will run when I press the <kbd>Run</kbd> button.

My importing code in `__init__.py` is as follows:

```
from __resources__ import func_test
func_test()
```

However, `from __resources__` gives an error: `Unresolved reference '__resources__'`.

This is my project's file structure:

[image: Project Structure]

I think it might have something to do with `PYTHONPATH` or `PATH` environment variables, but I'm not sure what to change. I added the directory to both paths.

Comment: Underscore placement is important. `__init.py__` is not `__init__.py`, and `__resources.py__` is not `__resources__.py`. Also, `.py` doesn't go in the `import` statement.

Comment: Works fine for me in both Python 2.7.13 and 3.6.1. I created the module and saved it in a **file** named `__resources__.py` in the same directory as the file that contains the code in your question.

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix the config @martineau

Comment: How are you executing the code in the `__init__.py` file? Files with that name are used to make the directory they are in into a package and are implicitly executed when you try to `import` a module in the package using the name of the directory in which the two files reside.

Comment: It's my main class that runs in Intellij. @martineau

Comment: Your main class must be in a file somewhere. I suggest you [edit] your question and show the directory and file structure involved. I made some assumptions earlier that may not have been true when I claimed it worked for me.

Comment: @martineau Added Project Structure.

Comment: Sorry, that structure doesn't make sense (or tell me what is triggering the execution of `__init__.py`. Suggest you read (or re-read) the documentation on how packages work in Python.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144100/discussion-between-evan-weissburg-and-martineau).

Comment: Sorry, gotta go.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put your main application code in `__init__.py`. Either use `__main__.py` (if you want to invoke the package directly, e.g. in a zip file) or just use a module named after your project (e.g. `foo.py`). You also should know that any symbol starting and ending with two underscores is reserved by Python -- you should avoid using any names with that pattern unless you're intending to make use of a documented feature of the language.

Comment: __init__.py was autogenerated when I made a source folder, so it shouldn't be an issue, right? I renamed the __resources__.py folder to resources.py, but it didn't fix my problem. Thanks for the naming advice though.

Comment: After that fix, invalidating and restarting fixed my issue. Thanks! Just make sure you don't have __ around the file name.